# What do the Turkish people think about the 15-16 July 2016's coup d'état?

Tags: turkey, coup

Two weeks after the coup against(?) Erdogan, there are uncertainties about it;

- [It was a quasi-coup](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/11709/is-president-erdogan-of-turkey-staging-a-coup-attempt/11711#11711),
- CIA is behind it,
- it is done by Fethullah Gülen,
- ...

Is there a poll (not by a Turkish source) that specifies what Turkish people think about it?

Comment: This is far too broad. I guess, there are citizens of Turkey who have each of the listed opinions (and a dozen more). Possibility of running any independent polls are also highly questionable — at least, at the moment.

Comment: I'm not sure there are reliable, unbiased polling organizations capable of polling in Turkey at the moment - never mind anyone having ability to overcome the "i aint't gonna say anything that will get me thrown in jail" response bias.

Comment: Basically, if you ARE a Turkish citizen and someone rings you up asking about the coup, your first guess would be "agent of the state law enforcement" and not "reputable polling firm, guaranteeing my anonymity"

Comment: The willingness of citizens to freely express their opinions about their government varies from country-to-country around the world. This is true no matter who is asking the questions. They generally fear retribution for speaking ill against the government. Particularly in less democratic nations. Therefore, any polling on the topic of the OP is non-existent today and unlikely moving forward.